# Watchkit error: WatchKit Extension contains multiple WatchKit apps

Tags: ios, compiler-errors, bundle, watchkit, apple-watch

I am getting this error when I compile my watchkit app

Embedded binary validation utility error

```
error: WatchKit Extension contains multiple WatchKit apps whose bundle     
identifiers match "com.tec.MyApp.watchkitapp". It can only have one
```

Any clue..? :)

Comment: clue = "It can only have one"

Comment: My app does have only one, and was building fine all week, then suddenly this happened. But cleaning and building again fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

This are the steps that worked for me:

1. Clean all project dir (options+clean)
2. Close Xcode
3. Delete "Derived Data"
4. Rebuild everything

Answer (score 2):

A .app can contain just one Apple Watch companion app. If you want multiple Watch-apps, you must create another iPhone app with it.

Answer (score 2):

Check that your bundle identifier is correct in all target.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your extension and your app uses a different bundle identifier

Answer (score 0):

XCode Menu => Product => Clean Build Folder

Build Project & Run it